# Запятая в предложении с двумя вставками

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вставная-конструкция

Отвечала на вопрос о вставных конструкциях. Попалось вот такое предложение (в двух вариантах пунктуации):

**А Каракатица — так по-настоящему называют Госпожу К. — не спеша, — ведь она была уверена, что Добыча** [sic] **от неё не уйдёт! — бесшумно подплывала всё ближе и ближе.**
[**Б. Заходер. Отшельник и Роза (1)**](https://profilib.net/chtenie/38741/boris-zakhoder-otshelnik-i-roza-3.php)

**А Каракатица (так по-настоящему называют Госпожу К.) не спеша — ведь она была уверена, что добыча от неё не уйдёт! — бесшумно подплывала всё ближе.**
[**Б. Заходер. Отшельник и роза (2)**](http://afield.org.ua/book/zahoder.html)

В одном варианте скобки заменены на тире — это понятно.
А вот нужна ли запятая после "не спеша"? Запуталась — не могу решить.
Как бы Вы оформили это предложение?

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, запятая все же нужна. Поскольку деепричастие "не спеша" уже почти утратило глагольное значение. А в словаре Ефремовой, например, не спеша дается c помет. нареч. качеств. -обстоят. Да и в данном контексте оно имеет наречное значение: медленно.

Таким образом, не спеша и бесшумно можно признать однородными членами и на этом основании поставить запятую.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, запятая нужна: вставка добавлена к одному из бессоюзно связанных однородных членов предложения, выраженных разными частями речи. Это близкие по смыслу обстоятельства образа действия "не спеша" (ср. "неспешно") и "бесшумно".

**P.S.** http://russkiy-na-5.ru/articles/444

> *Чаще всего* однородные члены предложения выражаются словами одной части речи, но возможны и такие однородные члены, которые выражены
>   словами разных частей речи, словосочетаниями и фразеологизмами. То
>   есть однородные члены могут быть по-разному оформлены грамматически.
>   *Девочка отвечала на экзамене бойко, толково, прекрасным языком.*

На мой взгляд, запятая здесь нужна именно из формальных соображений и только авторская идея придать первому элементу особый смысл (этой самой вставкой) может сделать допустимым иное его грамматическое истолкование.

Comment: @ Alex_ander, почему разными частями речи? Вы же сами пишете, что это  обстоятельства образа действия.

Comment: Деепричастие и наречие - разные части речи, но как _члены предложения_ оба могут быть обстоятельствами.

Answer (score 1):

На мой вкус - не нужна.

Давайте "от печки". Если не углубляться в детали, таки запятые проставляются тогда и только тогда, когда они нужны во фразе без вставок. Или по-умному, если дни есть мотив иной, чем оформление конструкции, оформленной как вставка.
То есть имеем.

*Каракатица не спеша(,) бесшумно подплывала всё ближе и ближе.*

Ну и зачем здесь запятая?! 
Идея Alex_ander, что здесь однородные члены, меня не вдохновляет. Как раз неоднородные - именно в силу  того, что выражены разными частями речи. В таких случаях надо иметь очень сильную авторскую мотивацию, чтобы счесть "разнородные" члены однородными.

Вопрос несколько осложняется тем, что выбор между неоднорностью и однородностью членов часто предопределяется только авторским пониманием, формальных критериев тут нет (кроме случаев, когда запятая существенно меняет смысл сказанного). Поэтому исключить однородность тут невозможно. Но вот нашлось интересное соображение в пользу неоднородности. Однородные - по мысли автора - члены тут были бы соединены союзом И, исключающим какую-либо неоднозначность прочтения.

> 2. Однородные члены обычно выражаются одной и той же частью речи.
>
> Но однородные члены могут быть и морфологически разнородными:
>
> Вошёл молодой человек лет двадцати пяти, блещущий здоровьем, со
>   смеющимися щеками, губами и глазами. В данном предложении среди
>   однородных определений первое выражено именным словосочетанием в
>   родительном падеже (лет двадцати пяти), второе – причастным оборотом
>   (блещущий здоровьем), третье – сочетанием трёх существительных в
>   творительном падеже с предлогом с с зависимым причастием (со
>   смеющимися щеками, губами и глазами).
>
> Примечание. Иногда сочинительная связь может соединять и разноимённые
>   члены предложения, например: Неизвестно, кто и как разнес по тайге
>   весть о гибели старого сокжоя (Федосеев). Союзные слова в придаточном
>   предложении являются разными членами предложения (подлежащее кто и
>   обстоятельство образа действия как, но связаны они сочинительным
>   союзом и).

http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/723-27_odnorodnye_chleny_predlozheniya.html

Источник, понятно, не авторитетный, но формулировка сама по себе весьма убедительна.

Короче, повторюсь, мне запятая кажется излишней.

Comment: @ Мимоходов,почему не авторитетный?  Материалы сайта представляют собой электронную версию книги д.ф.н., проф. Балашовой Л.В. и д.ф.н., проф. Дементьева В.В. «Курс русского языка».

Comment: @plotnikov.tosha2016 Хорошо если так. Я, признаться, не видел этого, спасибо. Но все равно, "электронная версия" чего-то не слишком известного  не может быть абсолютно авторитетным. Надо сравнивать с бумажным оригиналом, а у меня его, понятное дело нет. Вот если бы это скан был...

Comment: Фраза "на мой вкус" в данном контексте абсолютно неуместна. Даже если это юмор такой. Все-таки здесь должны быть образцы грамотной речи.

Comment: @Инна во-первых, вы слишком придирчивы. На мой вкус - не юмор, а вполне грамотное выражение. Во-вторых, за "образцами" вам не сюда. Образцы культуры речи сюда не ходят. Есть несколько специалистов, но не узкопрофильных.

Answer (score 1):

Однородные обстоятельства образа действия имеют признаки однородности такие же, как и  однородные определения. Признаков однородности определений много:

• обозначают признаки однородных предметов: синие, желтые, красные шары;

• обозначают взаимозависимые в условиях контекста признаки (= так как, поэтому): лунный, ясный вечер (= ясный, потому что лунный);

• обозначают художественные образы, метафоры: свинцовые, погасшие глаза;

• присутствует смысловая градация: радостное, праздничное, лучезарное настроение;

• одиночное определение расположено перед распространенным: пустое, запорошенное снегом поле;

• расположены после определяемого слова: женщина молодая, прекрасная, добрая, интеллигентная, обаятельная;

• обозначают субъективную характеристику (факультативный признак): маленькое, золотистое облачко; длинный, узкий ковер;

• в позиции после определяемого слова: облака круглые, высокие, золотисто-серые, с нежными белыми краями.

• обозначают синонимичные в условиях контекста признаки, при этом в условиях контекста они объединяются каким-нибудь общим признаком (сходством производимого ими впечатления, внешним видом и т.д.): Он протягивал мне красную, опухшую, грязную руку; Тяжелые, холодные тучи лежали на вершинах окрестных гор; В густых, темных волосах блестели седые пряди; бледное, строгое лицо; веселый, добродушный смех; пустынный, неприветливый дом; ласковые, живые глаза; гордый, храбрый вид; сухие, потрескавшиеся губы; тяжелое, злое чувство; серый, непрерывный, мелкий дождь и т.д.

Последний пункт как раз отражает нашу ситуацию- сходство производимого впечатления. Не спеша, бесшумно - есть общий признак "спокойно". Можно же сказать неспешно **и** бесшумно - образованы оба наречия от качественных прилагательных, вот если бы одно было качественным, а другое относительным - были бы неоднородны. Это такой переходный признак однородности - как автор сочтёт, так и будет.

В первом издании книги Б.Заходера предложение  оформлено с запятой. Видимо, это авторское оформление. Вообще, Б.Заходер - грамотный писатель, но второе издание можно назвать идеальным (Издательство "Речь") - там и иллюстратор замечательный, и корректор очень грамотный. Видимо, он ему предложил убрать два тире при вставных конструкциях и указал на неоднородность. Фраза стала более стройной, содержание не пострадало.

Answer (score 1):

Это предложение оформляется по-разному, но мне кажется, что лучший вариант выглядит так:

**Каракатица (так по-настоящему называют Госпожу К.) не спеша — ведь она была уверена, что добыча от неё не уйдёт! — бесшумно подплывала всё ближе.**

Пояснение

1) Здесь две вставки имеют разное оформление (с помощью скобок и тире), и это правильное решение, так как четыре тире смотрятся не лучшим образом.

2) Вторая вставка относится к слову ***не спеша***, она не должна отделяться от него запятой.

3) Обстоятельства ***не спеша*** и ***бесшумно*** по смыслу однородными не являются. Но если они стоят рядом (без вставки), то между ними ставится запятая (тогда они считаются однородными, имеющими сближенное значение). Однако  **при наличии вставки нет необходимости в сближении значений**, поэтому **запятая не ставится**.

Answer (score 0):

Допустим даже, что обстоятельства однородны (что спорно). Тогда запятая должна ставиться, но ПОСЛЕ вставки:

*... не спеша — ведь она была уверена в себе, — бесшумно подплывала всё ближе...*

А у нас там — подчиненное предложение, которое все равно требует запятой, да еще и восклицательный знак, который все запятые "поглотил". Так что споры напрасны.

А откуда взялась запятая ПЕРЕД вставкой, ни при каком раскладе не могу понять.